# Whats the name of the package for grub2

Tags: bootloader

I need to run `update-grub` because I've compiled a new kernel but the `update-grub` command is not installed.  What is the name of the package for the Raspberry Pi that provides this program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need grub on the Raspberry Pi, but you do need to do a few more steps as explained [here](http://elinux.org/Raspberry_Pi_Kernel_Compilation#Transfer_the_build).

Comment: Thanks.  Explains why I couldn't find it.  I was following a more generic linux kernel compilation guide.  I'll try again with the guide you linked.  But as an aside if not grub, then how does it the RPi boot?

Comment: @dpetican It's hardcoded into the Pi. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6139952/what-is-the-booting-process-for-arm